# Multiple bouncing dots issue

Tags: java, swing, timer

I trying to animate 50 bouncing dots with different colours. I am able to make the dots move but the dots drag on like it is being painted. I do not know why it turned to be like this

[image]

This is my codes for DotsPanel:

```
public DotsPanel(){

    frameSize = 300;
    setBounds (100, 100,frameSize,frameSize );
    setPreferredSize (new Dimension(frameSize, frameSize));
    setVisible(true);

    x = 0;
    y = 40;
    moveX = moveY = 3;


    for (int i = 0; i < dot.length; i++)
    {
        dot[i] = new Dot (frameSize, frameSize);
    }

    timer = new Timer(DELAY, new TimerListener());  
    timer.start();      
}

private class TimerListener implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < dot.length; i++)
        {
            dot[i].animate();       
        }
        repaint();      
    }
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

    for (int i = 0; i < dot.length; i++)
    {
        dot[i].draw(g);             
    }
}

public void run ()
{   
    while(true)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dot.length; i++)
        {
            dot[i].animate();       
        }   
        repaint();  
    }
}
```

This is the Dot class:

```
public Dot(int width, int height) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    x = r.nextInt(width - d);
    y = r.nextInt(height - d);
    speed = r.nextInt(10);
    red = r.nextInt(256);
    green = r.nextInt(256);
    blue = r.nextInt(256);
    moveX = moveY = 3;
}

public void animate ()
{           
    x += moveX;
    y += moveY;
    if (x <= 0 || x >= 300)
            moveX = moveX * -1;
    if (y <= 0 || y >= 300)
        moveY = moveY * -1;
}

public void draw(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(new Color(red, green, blue));
    //g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillOval(x, y, d, d);

}
```

I do not know which part went wrong. I am guessing is the draw method. I tried using paint instead of paintComponent but still the same result. And if i remove the while loop, the dots do not animate, I did this according to a tutorial i seen in youtube, the tutorial works well though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I guess it's simply because you don't "clear" the previous drawing each time a new one is drawn. As a result, you see all your previous graphics being continuously stacked !

EDIT (correct solution by ***camickr*** in comments below) :

> The solution is to invoke `super.paintComponent(g)` at the top of the method to invoke the default painting functionality, which for a JPanel, will paint the background for you.

Comment: Right reason, wrong solution. The solution is to invoke `super.paintComponent(g)` at the top of the method to invoke the default painting functionality, which for a JPanel,  will paint the background for you.

Comment: @camickr Oh really, I didn't know that the super method call could automatically paint the background... Gonna fix all my programs now, thanks alot !